# How to format code on GitHub with backticks, spaces, code and pre?

Tags: github

I am struggling to format my code on GitHub, can somebody help me understand the logic behind it?

[image]

This QA was inspired by an actual discussion https://github.com/GrapesJS/grapesjs/discussions/5711

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion is to always use the "Preview" function before posting, to make sure nothing breaks.
[image: Preview button]

And then here are my general observations for how formatting code on github works.
I learned this by trial and error, one thing I learned even right now while trying to explain this and I bet there is an official guide somewhere too.

### formatting lines of code or blocks with `` ` ``, ```` ``` ```` and

To format a line, simply use a single backtick like this `` `hello` ``, result: `hello`.

For blocks, you can either use **three backticks** at the start and end of the block ```` ``` ````, like this

> ````
> ```
> function hello() {
>   // ...
> }
> ```
> ````

result:

```
function hello() {
  // ...
}
```

or **four spaces** at the start of each line. The easiest way is to select the code in IDE and press <kbd>tab</kbd>, which will increase the indentation for the whole selected code

> ```
>     function world() {
>       // ...
>     }
> ```

result:

```
function world() {
  // ...
}
```

### formatting code that contains other formatting symbols

To do that, you can use `<code>single line</code>` if the code needs to contain `` backticks ` `` ,
or `<pre>` for blocks, which stands for preformatted text. Especially useful if you struggle to format your code with backticks.

> ```
> <pre>
> function lorem() {
>   // ...
> }
> </pre>
> ```

result:

```
function lorem() {
  // ...
}
```

### quirks - confused code formatting

Anyway, especially weird situation happens when you mix everything together, like I did above

```
needs to contain <code>backticks ` </code> , or `<pre>` for blocks, which ...
```

Which gets confusingly translated as nested code, which I didn't even know was possible 
*(note: Interestingly, on StackOverflow, the nested highlighting doesn't happen, but the rest looks the same.)*

result:

> needs to contain `backticks </code> , or for blocks, which ...`

To fight against this confusion, it is possible to add additional backticks `` `hi` `` -> ``` ``hi`` ```, which will allow the engine to differentiate between different groups

```
`hi` -> ``hi``
```

And by combining four spaces, code blocks and backticks, what you see above can be achieved.

```
<code>\`hi\`</code> -> <code>\`\`hi\`\`</code>
```

This is what I actually see

[image: code screenshot]

Hope this helps getting the answer you seek by better formulating your question, cheers!